# Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ have a left inverse. Show that $AB$ has a left inverse.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Let $A$ be an $m×n$ matrix and $B$ be an $n×p$ matrix. Suppose that both $A$ and $B$ have a left inverse. Show that $AB$ has a left inverse.

So I know that $A_L^{-1}A=I$ so then $B_LB^{-1}B=I$. Therefore $(A_L^{-1}A)(B_LB^{-1}B)=I^2=I$

Looking for see if this proof is correct

Comment: You need to find a matrix $X$ such that $XAB = I$. That is not what you have done here. (Also, $A_L^-1$ should be written $A_L^{-1}$ - put {} around the $-1$.)

Comment: Um, so what is $ (AB)^{-1} $.  You never answered that $X (AB)=I $.  You didn't multiply AB times any thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write $(B_L^{-1}A_L^{-1})AB=I$, so $(B_L^{-1}A_L^{-1})$ is the left inverse of $AB$.

Comment: @ Tsemo Aristide and that shows that AB has a left inverse?

Comment: Yes, it shows that $AB$ has a left inverse by definition, since there exists $X$ such that $X(AB)=I$, for example, $X=B_L^{-1}A_L^{-1}$.

Comment: awesome thanks for your help